# Equivalent definitions of algebra homomorphisms

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

I'm studying Atiyah-Macdonald's commutative algebra book and I'm trying to prove this equivalence:

[image]

**One implication**

If $h\circ f=g$. I can prove that $h(ax)=ah(x)$ but I have failed to prove that $f(x_1+x_2)=f(x_1)+f(x_2)$ (in order to complete the proof of A-module homomorphism) and $f(x_1x_2)=f(x_1)f(x_2)$ (to complete the prove of ring homomorphism). what I proved was $h(f(x_1)+f(x_2))=h(f(x_1))+h(f(x_2))$ and $hf(x_1)hf(x_2)=h(f(x_1))h(f(x_2))$ since $f$ is not necessarily surjective, we don't have that $h$ is a A-algebra homomorphism.

**Another implication**

I need hints, I have no idea how to proceed.

I need help.

Thanks a lot

Comment: $f$ is a ring homomorphism, by assumption...

Comment: I think what Atiyah-Macdonald mean was: A *ring homomorphism* $h \colon B \to C$ is a homomorphism of $A$-algebras iff $h \circ f = g$ ... so you're done.

Comment: @martini yes, I suspected that, thank you, now it remains only one side of the implication.

Comment: @ZevChonoles yes, you're right. Now, it remains only one side of the implication :)

Comment: @martini thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the implication shown, it is required that $h$ is a homomorphism of rings, the cited statement is to read as follows:

> For ring homomorphisms $f \colon A \to B$ and $g \colon A \to C$ a homomorphism of rings $h \colon B \to C$ is a homormorphism of $A$-algebras iff $g = h \circ f$.

For the missing implication, note that the $A$-module structures are given by $f$ and $g$ respectively, we have for $a \in A$ if $h$ is an $A$-module homomorphism: 
\begin{align*}
  (h\circ f)(a) &= h\bigl(f(a)\bigr)\\
       &= h(a \cdot 1_B)\\
       &= a \cdot h(1_B)\\
       &= a \cdot 1_C\\
       &= g(a)
\end{align*}
So $g = h \circ f$.